# Calculating bounding box using getBoundingClientRect() Issue with swift top, left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with absolute position `target`, I need to create another div `bb` which perfectly **match/overlap** the bounding box for `target`.

The following script works, but at same rotation like 80 degree, the position of div `bb` is not kept.

I would like to know:

- What am I doing wrong in my code? How to fix it?
- Or could be a problem getBoundingClientRect()?

Notes: initial position of div `bb` match div `target`, I need to swift `bb` using only `CSS translate`

http://jsbin.com/josufehano/1/
[chrome]

Issue could be in the following function, but any other feedback sis really appreciated. Thanks.

```
    calculate: function () {
        var elm = document.getElementById(this.config.target.id);
        var rect = elm.getBoundingClientRect();
        this.data.br.width = rect.width;
        this.data.br.height = rect.height;
        // calculate swift
        this.data.br.left = -Math.abs(this.data.br.width - this.data.width) / 2;
        this.data.br.top = -Math.abs(this.data.br.height - this.data.height) / 2;

    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem using the following script.
Basically I need it to consider the rotation when calculating top/left swift.

http://jsbin.com/hejemixolu/1/

```
        calculate: function () {
            var elm = document.getElementById(this.config.target.id);
            var rect = elm.getBoundingClientRect();
            this.data.br.width = rect.width;
            this.data.br.height = rect.height;
            this.data.br.left = rect.left;
            this.data.br.top = rect.top;
            if (this.data.br.left <= this.data.left) {
                this.data.br.left = -Math.abs(this.data.left - this.data.br.left);
            } else {
                this.data.br.left = Math.abs(this.data.br.left - this.data.left);
            }
            if (this.data.br.top <= this.data.top) {
                this.data.br.top = -Math.abs(this.data.top - this.data.br.top);
            } else {
                this.data.br.top = Math.abs(this.data.br.top - this.data.top);
            }
        },
```